# The optimal number of TCP/IP connection to transfer large file locally

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, tcp, internals

I need to transfer large file over tcp/ip locally via sockets. I need best possible performance. What is the optimal simulations connections count and why?  (I mean that I can use 1, 2, 3, ... sockets to send the same file parts in parallel).

I think that the best performance I will get with 1 simulations connection because IO performance is not parallelized well, there is not much processor involved.  And usually you will even got performance degradation if you, for example, will write file from several thread via one.  But tests results says that this is not always true for network transfer.

Comment: 'Not paralyzed well'? Do you mean 'not *parallelized* well'?

Comment: @CodeCaster I can make tests... but I need to do this and different envs with different memory/proc/hdd/networrk/loading this is very long process.. and I need understanding WHY optimal connection count ma be > 1 not just test results.. maybe some one expirienced know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One socket is perfectly capable of utilizing the available bandwidth. Read [Wifi TCP iperf throughput: 1 stream vs multiple streams?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/wifi-tcp-iperf-throughput-1-stream-vs-multiple-streams).